# Rotation in ios7 with Auto Layout with 6 buttons from ( 2 x 3 ) to ( 3 x 2 )

Tags: button, rotation, ios7, xcode5, autolayout

I was trying to figure out how to use autolayout in my project but i didn't found any usefull tutorials for my case.

So here is what looks like in portrait :

```
[  ------------  ------------  ]
[  | Button1  |  | Button2  |  ]
[  ------------  ------------  ]
[                              ]
[  ------------  ------------  ]
[  | Button3  |  | Button4  |  ]
[  ------------  ------------  ]
[                              ]
[  ------------  ------------  ]
[  | Button5  |  | Button6  |  ]
[  ------------  ------------  ]
[                              ]
```

and here is in in landscape :

```
[  ------------  ------------                ]
[  | Button1  |  | Button2  |                ]
[  ------------  ------------                ]
[                                            ]
[  ------------  ------------                ]
[  | Button3  |  | Button4  |                ]
[  ------------  ------------                ]
[                                            ]
```

So i want the button 5 to go up and near button2 when rotating and button 6 to go near button 4. Like this:

```
[  ------------  ------------  ------------   ]
[  | Button1  |  | Button2  |  | Button5  |   ]
[  ------------  ------------  ------------   ]
[                                             ]
[  ------------  ------------  ------------   ]
[  | Button3  |  | Button4  |  | Button6  |   ]
[  ------------  ------------  ------------   ]
[                                             ]
```

***I'm really sorry about the notepad-like schemes but i can't upload images and that's the best i can do***

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you are trying to do this in the storyboard or in code.  At first glance, I don't think it is possible to change layout constraint relationships like this simply within the storyboard.  However, you do have the power to change these relationships programatically upon rotation.

Comment: I expected an answer for storyboard

Comment: This looks more like a job for the Flow Layout (e.g. UICollectionView). Here's the companion guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UICollectionView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UICollectionView

Comment: This post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20683698/1239263

Comment: @bilobatum: your link refers to an outdated answer. iOS7 is only available with Xcode 5 where multipliers are gone. I agree with bilobatum: I'd think about collection view (or setting them in code)