# Easiest way to move view on left to the top when rotating device

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I'm creating and app in iOS 7 for the iPad that supports all orientations. On one of my views, I have 2 images views: one on the left of the view, and one on the right.

This is in landscape mode, but when the device rotates, I want the imageview on the left to rotate and move to the top of the view, and the imageview on the right to rotate and move to the bottom.

What's the easiest way of doing this with autolayout? I'm currently doing the following:

```
    - (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
        float leftAngle = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) ? M_PI_2 : 0.0;
        float rightAngle = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) ? -M_PI_2 : 0.0;
        _leftLeafsImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(leftAngle);
        _rightLeafsImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rightAngle);

        [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    }
```

The result of this is that the views move before rotating which isn't desired, and also the far right view ends up at the top and not the bottom.

Any help is much appreciated as I'm pretty confused with it :(

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to use transforms to rotate views in response to device rotation. As long as rotation is supported by your app, then the view controller's root view (i.e., self.view) will rotate automatically and will bring along all of its subviews for the ride. In response to device rotation, you only need to concern yourself with a subview's size and position along the horizontal and vertical axes.

You can use Auto Layout to configure totally different layouts for both orientations. However, I don't believe there's an easy solution. There's a discussion about it here: [How to configure different layouts for Portrait and Landscape Orientations using Auto Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20683698/1239263)

Comment: I know that the rotation will automatically move things around, but I want my image views to show the image rotate as well. Autolayout will leave them the same orientation. So if for example the image was of the letter A, autolayout would still show it as an 'A' when rotated, but I want it to display as a horizontal 'A' when rotated hence the translation