# Aligning two buttons in portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

So I'm trying to align this two buttons using autolayout.
In portrait they are ok:
[image: In portrait]

But when switching to landscape:
[image: Landscape]

EDIT:
Current Constraints:

[image]

Results obtained with that constraints:
[image]

I need the buttons aligned side by side in landscape.

Have tried multiples constraints but without much luck yet.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the Autolayout constraints you've already tried? Also, in the second screenshot, how are the buttons supposed to be aligned? Like in the first screenshot (aligned one below the other), or differently (side-by-side)?

Comment: I'm sorry! I didn't say how it suppose to be aligned when in landscape. Yes, they supposed to be side by side. So far the constraints are as follows: Red Button: Top Space to layout, leading space to superview. Green Button: Trailing space to superview, Bottom space to superview. Buttons width and height equally.

Comment: Then it means the layout will be different depending on the device orientation: I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do that visually with the interface builder. You will need to design your constraints programmatically and change them at runtime when the orientation changes. Unfortunately I'm not tech-savvy enough in Autolayout constraints by code, but you can get some inspiration here, it seems the goal is pretty much the same as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20687356/145997.

Comment: Thank you Romain, will take a look to that post.

Comment: Romain, I used what it's described in the post you point me to. Now my buttons are perfectly aligned portrait and landscape. Thank you.

Comment: @Romain should put his "solution" in an answer, to be accepted by the OP :-)

Comment: @Romain, yes do that so I can vote your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout you're willing to achieve depends on the device orientation: it's generally not possible to do that visually within Xcode and the interface builder. You will need to design your constraints programmatically and update them at runtime when the orientation changes.

You can get some inspiration here, it seems the goal is pretty much the same as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20687356/145997.