# Different sets of auto layout constraints for different orientation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've seen similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683698/how-to-configure-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations-using) but it isn't really close to my case

So I have different screen layouts for different orientations. App is using storyboards.
To have a better understanding I attach photo of the UI sketch
[image: UI Sketch]

As you can see there is a TableView and a Toolbar (a custom one). Toolbar contains 2 labels and a button.

So portrait constraints are:

- Toolbar height 80pts
- Toolbar trailing and leading space == 0
- TableView's top space from navbar == 0
- TableView's bottom space from Toolbar = 0
- Tableview's width == Toolbar width
- Labels vertically centred inside toolbar, have fixed size and fixed distance from left and right
- Button has fixed sizes and centred inside toolbar

Landscape constraints are totally different:

- Toolbar width 80pts
- Toolbar top (from navbar) and bottom space == 0
- Toolbar trailing space == 0
- TableView's leading space  == 0
- TableView's trailing space from Toolbar = 0
- Tableview's height == Toolbar width
- Labels horizontally centred inside toolbar, have fixed size and fixed distance from top and bottom
- Button has fixed sizes and centred inside toolbar

I've tried to delete all constraints from storyboard and add them programmatically. But Xcode add them during compilation automatically. I've tried to delete all constraints inside root view but probably I didn't go properly through all views tree as several constrains aren't deleted.

Do you have any idea how that can be implemented in a proper way?

This is my first experience with Auto Layout and it isn't that easy as I expected.

Here my solution which doesn't work (as Xcode adds some constraints during compilation)

```
// Those properties store all constraints for portrait and landscape modes
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *portraitConstraints;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *landscapeConstraints;

-(void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    BOOL layoutIsPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);

    if (layoutIsPortrait) {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.landscapeConstraints)
            [constraint remove];

        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.portraitConstraints)
            [constraint install];
    } else {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.portraitConstraints)
            [constraint remove];

        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.landscapeConstraints)
            [constraint install];
    }

}

- (NSArray *)portraitConstraints {
    if (!_portraitConstraints) {
        UIView *mainTable = self.myTableView;
        UIView *toolbar = self.toolbarView;
        UIView *firstLabel = self.firstLabel;
        UIView *secondLabel = self.secondLabel;
        UIView *bigButton = self.bigButton;
        UIView *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;

        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mainTable,toolbar,firstLabel,secondLabel,bigButton,navBar);

        NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray array];
        [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[toolbar(==80)]|"
                                          options:0
                                          metrics:nil
                                          views:views]];
        [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[navBar][mainTable][toolbar]|"
                                          options:0
                                          metrics:nil
                                          views:views]];
        // MORE AND MORE CONSTRAINTS ADDED HERE

        _portraitConstraints = constraints;
    }
    return _portraitConstraints;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you're using is certainly possible, but will involve quite a bit of code to get the layout you're looking for. An easier way to to this would be to delete your controller's view in the storyboard (you can copy and paste it into the xib file if you want), and instead make its views, one each for portrait and landscape, in a xib file. You can do all you constraint setup there, and only have to switch between the two views in code. You can create both views in one xib file -- I created the portrait one first, so it will be the first object in the array you get back from loading the nib.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIView *pView;;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIView *lView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *leftLabel;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *rightLabel;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)loadView {
    NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PortraitAndLandscapeViews" owner:self options:nil];
    self.pView = views[0];
    self.lView = views[1];
    self.view = self.pView;
}



-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    BOOL layoutIsPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);
    if (layoutIsPortrait) {
        self.view = self.pView;
        self.leftLabel = [self.view viewWithTag:11];
        self.rightLabel = [self.view viewWithTag:12];
    }else{
        self.view = self.lView;
        self.leftLabel = [self.view viewWithTag:21];
        self.rightLabel = [self.view viewWithTag:22];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a good idea.
But it means that only possible (and appropriate) transition animation will be crossfade. Am I right?

Comment: @OgreSwamp, maybe yes, but doing it in code won't be any different. I'm not even sure that you can do a cross fade during a rotation between orientations.

Comment: Well... doing it in code (removing and setting constraints) will have animation by default. UIKit animates if you change constraints as far as I know.
I think crossfade should be possible though - I can make a screenshot, set it on top of new view and decrease alfa in 0.5 sec to 0.0.

Comment: @OgreSwamp, no, constraints aren't animated if you change them (delete then add a new one), or if you change the constant value (unless you do it in an animation block). You might be able to do the screen shot thing, that's something I've never tried.

Comment: thanks. Found another issue with this approach. I have IBOutlets in my .xib. If I connect same outlets in second .xib and they load them - IBOutlets in my controller will refer to the latest loaded view.

Comment: @OgreSwamp, you can add tags to the subviews, and set your properties (instead of outlets) based on those -- I updated my answer to show how I did this. If you make the file's owner of the xib your view controller, you can still connect up IBActions to buttons in both views, but unfortunately, you can't do the outlets that way.